# Grouping or rows of excel by value in a column

Tags: r, excel, group-by

Say I have an excel sheet with two columns similar to below.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | 234 |
| Second | 234 |
| Third | 235 |

I'm looking for a way in either R or excel that I can break up or grough the cells to get

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | 234 |
| Second | 234 |

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Third | 235 |

So, I basically want to group the excel sheet up similar values in the column Another header.

Comment: df %>% group_split(Another_header)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly do you want these tables represented in the excel sheet?